Optimise text file statistics calculation by combination of grep, awk, cut
My goal is to calculate statistics from the file that contains the following lines:
2024-05-08 11:02:58,731 INFO o.a.j.a.J.Some check: Closest Day: Wed, New quantity for email0987@yahoo.com is: 1

What I need is to calculate how many emails have the same unique number. For example:
1 - 6575 emails
2 - 333 emails

and so on.
The file can potentially contain duplicate lines for the same email, so I filter that out using awk '!seen[$1]++'.
I have created bash script for that purpose. It works, however for the files of hundreds of MB it's tremendously slow and takes ages to calculate. Is there a way to optimise it? I suppose getting through line by line is not the best way.
#!/bin/bash

input_file="$1"

closest_date=$(grep "Closest Day:" "$input_file" | rev | cut -d' ' -f1,3 | rev | awk '!seen[$1]++')

declare -A counts

# Iterate over each line of closest_draw_data
while read -r line; do
    # Extract email and number
    email=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1)
    number=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f2)
    
    # Increment count for the number
    (( counts[$number]++ ))
done <<< "$closest_date"

# Print the counts
for number in "${!counts[@]}"; do
    echo "Number $number: ${counts[$number]}"
done


The problem is probably that while loop where you spawn two subshells in each loop (for email and number). The secret to bash optimization is to reduce subshells and subprocesses, and use bash builtins as much as possible. You can probably turn that loop into a single awk command and see a big speedup. The awk command should output text in a format that you can read into an associative array with only bash builtins.

Also, if you say that $closest_date can hundreds of MBs large, I think you shouldn't store it in a variable. You should put it in a file, or integrate it into the pipeline if you can.

Whar are you doing with $email? This variable seem not used? ^---^ SC2034 (warning): email appears unused. Verify use (or export if used externally).

Mayvbe this: echo $(($(sed -ne '/Closest Day/s/.*: /+/gp' <largeFile,txt !

Or, but I'm still nut sure about what you expect to do with $email, maybe this: declare -iA emails='()';. <(sed -ne <largeFile.txt  's/.*Closest Day.*for \(.*\) is: \([0-9]\+\) *$/emails["\1"]+=\2/p'), then declare -p emails .

please update the question with a sample set of input consisting of 8-10 lines making sure to have a few different emails and a couple duplicate lines; also update the question with the expected output making sure it corresponds witht the new set of input

you've stated you have multiple files ... do you need to sum up the emails on a per-file basis? or do you need to sum up the emails across all files?

it appears (to me) that you want to do a bit of counting and duplicate removals, all of which can probably be handled in a single awk script which in turn is going to be significantly faster than the current process; having said that, obtaining a workable solution is going to depend on you giving us a representative set of sample data and a clear explanation of what's to be done; see minimal reproducible example for info

what if a file contains multiple values for an email? eg. ... email0987@yahoo.com is: 1 and also ... email0987@yahoo.com is: 2 ?

1 sample input line and no expected output given that input doesn't demonstrate your requirements and so isn't adequate to test a potential solution with. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] including cases where 1 email address is associated with 2 different end of line numbers.

Thank you guys! awk solution worked for me best.
@jhnc if the file contains multiple values, i am all good to drop the second. But I am doing that on the stage of grepping initial logs, so what I am processing with awk doesn't require to handle duplicates.

You never need grep when you're using awk. foo | grep | awk is an anti-pattern.

You only posted 1 line of sample input and no expected output so we're all just guessing at what you might need but here's a GNU awk script (for arrays of arrays) and the output it produces from the input you provided in case this is what you're trying to do:
$ awk '
    /Closest Day/ { pairs[$NF][$(NF-2)] }
    END { for (nr in pairs) printf "%d - %d emails\n", nr, length(pairs[nr]) }
' file
1 - 1 emails

See why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for why your shell script is so slow, an equivalent awk script will be orders of magnitude faster.

Thanks so much - that worked for me as well as other awk solutions. That's definitely much faster.

It seems the entire script could be a single awk call:
awk '
    /Closest Day:/ && !seen[ $(NF-2) ]++ {
        counts[ $NF ]++
    }
    END {
        for (i in counts)
            printf "Number %d: %d\n", i, counts[i]
    }
' "$1"


If storing arrays of email and counts would consume too much memory, you could do:
awk '/Closest Day:/ { print $(NF-2),$NF }' "$1" |
sort -u -k1,1 |
cut -d' ' -f2 |
sort -n |
uniq -c |
awk '{ printf "Number %d: %d\n", $2, $1 }'

(sort only keeps a limited amount of data in memory and the other commands only need to buffer a single line.)

technically, email addresses could contain quoted space in the local part, and the domain is case-insensitive, but the original code didn't handle that either

Please replace that part
# Iterate over each line of closest_draw_data
while read -r line; do
    # Extract email and number
    email=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f1)
    number=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f2)
    
    # Increment count for the number
    (( counts[$number]++ ))
done <<< "$closest_date"

# Print the counts
for number in "${!counts[@]}"; do
    echo "Number $number: ${counts[$number]}"
done

using
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ]"}{counts[$2]+=1}END{for(number in counts){print "Number",number":",counts[number]}}' "$closest_date"

and then check if output is acceptable w.r.t. your requirements and if you get any speed up. This solution assumes you are accepting any order of lines in output, if you need certain order then set PROCINFO["sorted_in"] accordingly.
Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that space is field separator (to keep it consisent with your cut usage), for each line I increase value in array under key 2nd field value by 1. After lines are processed I use for loop to iterate over array and print information about key in values in form akin to your echo. Note that there is not , between number and : as there is no space there in your echo.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Thank you for comprehensive explanation. It worked for me.
